# Finding a linear system to solve quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, quadratics

considering an equality with a polynomial of second degree where the coefficient for $x^2$ is $1$ I know that

$$ a x^2 + b x + c = a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = 0 $$

I also know that

$$ \alpha + \beta = -b/a $$
$$ \alpha \times \beta = c/a $$

At this point I'm with some pen and paper and I'm trying to solve such problem ( finding $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ) using a linear system, and I'm looking for help .

If I think about this as a matrix, for me the way to describe the last 2 equalities involving $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is :
$$
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
\beta & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

and the $Ax=b$ system should look like ( I'm still a newbie, bear with me, I'm trying to derive a linear system for the first time )

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
\beta & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
? \\
? \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-b/a \\
c/a \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

At this point I have 2 major problems :

- I have no idea what to put inside the "x" column vector for the $Ax=b$ problem
- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not that useful in that position since in input I only have $a,b$ and $c$ ; I think I should rework this formulation and I don't know how .

I think that I'm on the right track because for a second degree polynomial I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix, I'm having troubles formulating the right linear system for this problem by soving the 2 problems listed above .

**EDIT 1**

After the observation that the "x" column vector should be something like $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}$ and that the division makes this a non-linear system, I tried to rework this further but I think that I need more help .

The only thing I remember that resembles a non linear behaviour simulated by a linear system / matrix , is an homogenous matrix, for example projective geometrive is non linear but computer aided rendering often times uses homogenous matrice / coordinates to do the job .

If this is the case I'm dead in the water because I never understood how this matrices really work and how to derive them .

The alternative is to exploit the fact that everything is divided by $a$ and so I can rewrite the "b" column vector by repositioning $a$ as a factor of the elements of the matrix . But I'm still confused about this because it will just complicate things .

Can you help me deploying this homogenous system ?

Comment: The equation $\alpha\times\beta = c/a$ is definitely not a linear equation for the unknowns $\alpha$ and $\beta$... So this is not a linear system. (Note that if you wanted to write a linear system using matrices, you had to take $x=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$.)

Comment: @paf I have made an edit with an explanation, see if it makes sense

Comment: I asked myself the same question about general polynomial equations

Comment: Why don't you just substitute in $\alpha$ or $\beta$ and solve a quadratic equation?

Comment: @harvey 1) I'm trying to find an alternative way to calculate / represent the same thing , 2) I'm trying to come up with a way to compute this and solve quadratics with an algorithm / formula that can be manipulated by a machine .